# Read the value of one specific node in an xml

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<Item>
    <Season>01</Season>
    <EpisodeNumber>01</EpisodeNumber>
    <EpisodeTitle>Title</EpisodeTitle>
</Item>
```

Every tag exists exactly one time in this xml file. I want to write the Episode Title in a label using Linq. What is the easiest way to do this? I know exactly the name of the node and it exists only one times. It should work without any for loops or something, shouldn't it?

I thought about something like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
string info = xml.Elements("EpisodeName").Value;
label1.Text = info;
```

but Elements has no method Value.

This one works, but can't I write this in less lines?

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var info = xml.Descendants("EpisodeName");
foreach (string line in info)
{
    label1.Text = line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value `Elements()` is a sequence (a series of values), which is why it has no `Value` property.  If you know that there will be at most one value, you can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to select out that value.  Here is a short program which pulls out the "Title" value:

```
static void Main()
{
    // I am loading the value from a string just for example; you can do XDocument.Load instead
    var xml = @"
        <Item>
            <Season>01</Season>
            <EpisodeNumber>01</EpisodeNumber>
            <EpisodeTitle>Title</EpisodeTitle>
        </Item>";
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    // this is the statement which extracts the first EpisodeTitle xml element without iterating
    var titleElem = xdoc.Root
        .Elements("EpisodeTitle")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // check to makes sure the element exists before calling .Value
    label1.Text = (titleElem == null) ? string.Empty : titleElem.Value;
}
```

I usually prefer to use `FirstOrDefault()` if there is a possibility that the value is missing from the xml; otherwise `First()` will throw an exception.

If you don't like having to check for null (and you're looking for a 1-liner), then you can use `DefaultIfEmpty()` after selecting out the value:

```
label1.Text = xdoc.Root.Elements("EpisodeTitle2").Select(e => e.Value).DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault();
```